# Display Mobile Compatible when it's on mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, mobile

Please allow me to ask a silly question about Google's site(google.com). I have tested their site with computer browsers and smartphone browsers. Okay! Here is the question that i have, when the time i make the computer browser to a small screen, the layout of Google's site does not fit in a mobile friendly layout. But, it does become mobile friendly layout when it's on mobile screen. But, the url is still same http://www.google.com.

I have tried other site, but other site is using 301 redirect when mobile screen detected and their url will be transferring to mobile url. I am curios about this how can google do this(change the mobile friendly web layout on mobile screen but keep same url). I keep thinking about this question until i can't sleep well. Is there anyone here know what is the trick google use?

Comment: It is using media queries to target small screen devices. Using media queries such as max-device-width will not be used when viewing on a desktop browser but it will be used on a device screen. See this reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Jackson, thanks for your comment. It would be a helpful article but it takes some time to read and understand when only doing testing. Will do the testing after i read it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is using Media queries:

```
@media only screen 
  and (min-device-width: 320px) 
  and (max-device-width: 480px)
  and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {

}
```

Check This **[link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)** for more details

is just css style when the website on mobile, for example you want a div not shown on mobile device you can do this:

```
@media only screen 
      and (max-width: 480px) {
    .yourdiv{display:none;}
    }
```

Check this **[example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_mediaquery)**

Comment: Hi Machine, i am just curios how to do it. And i have a few more questions after my first question started. I have a mobile friendly site. But, i don't really know what are the differences within `@media (max-width:00px)`, `@media all and (max-width:0px)`, `@media only screen {width:0px)`, `@media screen and (max-width:0px)`.

Comment: check this [link](http://www.blooberry.com/indexdot/css/topics/media.htm) and read Media Types and Descriptions table

@media only screen and (max-width:632px)
Here is a quote straight from W3C to explain this one.

The keyword ‘only’ can also be used to hide style sheets from older user agents. User agents must process media queries starting with ‘only’ as if the ‘only’ keyword was not present.
As there is no such media type as "only", the style sheet should be ignored by older browsers. and recommended  type is '@media only screen 
      and (max-width: 320px)'

Comment: Thanks @Machine! Learned a lot from that link. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you meant [viewport meta tag](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/) which fits layout of the page if it mobile device? 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`

Comment: Hi @Evgeniy, i tried this. It's not working as google's site.